# Issue with regular expression for identifying encrypted ids from string

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert certain patterns into links and it works fine as far as normal user ids are considered.But now i want to do the same for encrypted ids as well.

Below is my code:(works)

```
$text = "hi how are you guys???... @@[Sam Thomas:10181] @@[Jack Daniel:11074] @@[Paul Walker:11043] ";
$pattern = "/@@\[([^:]*):(\d*)\]/";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
$output = preg_replace($pattern, "<a href=\"http://localhost/$2\" class=\"tooltip\">$1</a>", $text);
```

Now i need to do link the text like:

```
"hi how are you guys???... @@[Sam Thomas:ZGNjAmD9ac3K] @@[Jack Daniel:ZGNjAmD9ac3K] @@[Paul Walker:ZGNjAmD9ac3K] ";
```

But this encrypted is not identified by above regular expression...

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/15 ??

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks it works also just changing \d* to \w* its now accepts both numbers and letters....

Answer (score 1):

```
@@\[([^:]*):(.*?)\]

             ^^
```

Try this.See demo.Just change `\d*` to `.*?` to accept anything or `\w*` to accept only numbers and letters.or `[^\]]*` or `[0-9a-zA-Z]` as well.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/52

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to accept numbers and letters as well.
Something like this -

```
@@\[([^:]*):([0-9a-zA-Z]*)\]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^ Replaced \d
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS1vL4/1)